# Python 3 - Find strings that appear in more than one list, the list are populated from function arguments

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I have a function which accepts any number of arguments:

```
def lists(*args):
```

When I execute this function it will be executed with arguments like the following:

```
lists(['g', 'gh', 'ghj', 'g'], ['j', 'ju', 'gh', 'gk', 'gn'])
```

These arguments form an multi-dimensional array (at least I think they do). So if I

```
print(args)
```

I get the following:

```
(['g', 'gh', 'ghj', 'g'], ['j', 'ju', 'gh', 'gk', 'gn'])
```

Which is what I'd expect.

The problem I'm trying to solve is printing out strings from the above lists which appear in more than one list.

In the above example I can convert the lists into one flat list and print out duplicates which is half right, it would print out

```
'g', 'gh'
```

Because there they both appear more than once, but what I really want it to print is just

```
'gh'
```

Because it's the only that appears in more than one list.

Am I going about this completely the wrong way, or do I just lack the knowledge of how to achieve this.

I've looked online and found a few examples of how to achieve something similar however it's all using integers not strings. I'm not sure if I'm setting up the arrays/lists correctly which means that any filtering I do fails.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You can convert both lists to a set, removing duplicates in each list. Then compare those sets for same elements maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
def lists(*args):
  if len(args)>=2:
    res = set(args[0])
  else:
    return set()
  for sub in args[1:]:
    res = res.intersection(sub)
  return res
```

Tests:

```
print(lists(['g', 'gh', 'ghj', 'g'], ['j', 'ju', 'gh', 'gk', 'gn']))  # -> {'gh'}

print(lists())  # -> set()

print(lists(['g', 'gh', 'ghj', 'g']))  # -> {'gh'}

print(lists(['g', 'gh', 'gn', 'g'], ['ju', 'gh', 'gk', 'gn'], ['gn', 'gh']))  # -> {'gh', 'gn'}
```

Note that the above code works with any amount of `list`s passed to the function.

---

The problem with your code was the flattening. By flattening you were losing info regarding whether the duplicates were in all `list`s or multiple times in one.

What my code is doing is (after checking that at least two `list`s are passed) converting every `list` to a `set` and calculating the intersection (common elements) over all. The calculation of the intersection is done in pairs (1rst `set` with 2nb, the result of the previous intersection with 3rd and so on).

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been banging my head against a wall for hours! Would you be able to explain the code a little more, I'm pretty new to python and would really want to get my head around what's going on here.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you again.